# How to reset selected options in select with custom value for options in angularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-select

I want to reset selected options in select with custom value for options in angularJS :

**HTML**

```
<select id="" name="" class="form-control" ng-model="mymodel">
    <option value="1000">All</option>
    <option value="-1">Not Done Yet</option>
    <option value="0">Already Done</option>
    <option value="1">Other option1</option>
    <option value="2">Other option1</option>
</select>
```

Select option is : `<span>{{mymodel}}</span>`

```
<button class="btn btn-danger glyphicon glyphicon-refresh"
    data-toggle="tooltip" title="Reset"
    ng-click="clearSearch();">Reset</button>
```

**JS**

```
$scope.clearSearch = function () {
    $scope.mymodel = 1000;
}
```

Comment: What version of AngularJS are you using? The answer that you accepted uses verison 1.0.1 in the JSFiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made this working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/24529/). It seems to work fine.

Note that I initialized the `$scope.mymodel`.

**JS**

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.mymodel = 1000;
    $scope.clearSearch = function () {
       $scope.mymodel = 1000;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have already done this initialization in my complete module but failed. I do not know where the issue is.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using AngularJS 1.4, you will need set values to a **string** instead of a number.

```
$scope.clearSearch = function () {
    //Use a string
    $scope.mymodel = '1000';
    //Not a number
    //$scope.mymodel = 1000;
}
```